# Java Android ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I am using `ExpandableListView` in an `Activity`. I have a `TextView` and a `CheckBox` in the `GroupView` . When I click the `CheckBox` the corresponding list item expands or collapses depending upon its state. I don't want to change the state of a list item on clicking the CheckBox in the GroupView. How can I achieve this?

This is my layout :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomPanel"
            android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:indicatorLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorRight" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomPanel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt_delete_group"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/delete_group" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt_add_group"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/add_group" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt_show_select"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/show_select" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And this is my adapter :

This is my Adapter after edit :

```
public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> expandableListTitle;
    private HashMap<String, List<RowBean>> expandableListDetail;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> selected = new ArrayList<>();
    private Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                       HashMap<String, List<RowBean>> expandableListDetail) {
        this.context = context;
        this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
        this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition)).get(expandedListPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return expandedListPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//        for(RowBean r : expandableListDetail.get(expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))){
//            Log.e("is select " , r.getTitle() + " " +r.isSelected() + " , " + listPosition + " ," +expandedListPosition);
//        }
        RowBean rowBean = (RowBean) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
        RowBean rowBean1 = expandableListDetail.get(expandableListTitle.get(listPosition)).get(expandedListPosition);
//        Log.e("rowbean " , rowBean1.getTitle() + " , " + rowBean1.isSelected() );
        final String expandedListText = rowBean.getTitle();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_holder, null);
        }
        TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItemCheckbox);
        expandedListTextView.setText(expandedListText);
        checkBox.setChecked(rowBean.isSelected());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.expandableListTitle.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
        return listPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int listPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewGroup groupview = parent;

        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("MAIN_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        final String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
        boolean[] sel = {RealmController.getGroup(listTitle, realm).isSelect()};
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.holder_layout, null);
        }
//        TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
//                .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);

        TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.showTextHolder);
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxHolder);
//        checkBox.setSelected(true);
//        if (pref.getInt(listTitle, 0) == 1) {
//            checkBox.setSelected(true);
//        } else {
//            checkBox.setSelected(false);
//        }

        final boolean[] st = new boolean[1];
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                if (!checkBox.isChecked()) {
//                    ExpandableListView gExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) groupview;
//                    gExpandableListView.expandGroup(listPosition);
////                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
//                    RealmResults<ObjectsInGroupRealm> objectsInGroupRealms = RealmController.getObjects(realm, listTitle);
//                    int position = -1;
//                    for (ObjectDefExtends objectDefExtends : Singleton.getInstance().getListaODE()) {
//                        for (ObjectsInGroupRealm o : objectsInGroupRealms) {
//                            if (o.getName().equals(objectDefExtends.name)) {
//                                position = Singleton.getInstance().getListaODE().indexOf(objectDefExtends);
//                                Singleton.getInstance().getListaODE().get(position).visible = false;
//                                editor.putInt(Singleton.getInstance().getListaODE().get(position).id.toString(), 0);
//                                editor.apply();
//                                RealmController.updateGroup(o.getGroupName(), false, realm);
//                                RealmController.updateObjectsInGroupRealm(o.getGroupName(), realm, context, false);
//                                FragmentGroupObjectsActivity.getArgument(context);
//                            }
//                        }
//                    }
//                    selected.remove(Integer.valueOf(listPosition));
//                } else {
//                    ExpandableListView gExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) groupview;
//                    gExpandableListView.expandGroup(listPosition);
////                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
//                    selected.add(listPosition);
//                    RealmResults<ObjectsInGroupRealm> objectsInGroupRealms = RealmController.getObjects(realm, listTitle);
//                    int position = -1;
//                    for (ObjectDefExtends objectDefExtends : Singleton.getInstance().getListaODE()) {
//                        for (ObjectsInGroupRealm o : objectsInGroupRealms) {
//                            if (o.getName().equals(objectDefExtends.name)) {
//                                position = Singleton.getInstance().getListaODE().indexOf(objectDefExtends);
//                                Singleton.getInstance().getListaODE().get(position).visible = true;
//                                editor.putInt(Singleton.getInstance().getListaODE().get(position).id.toString(), 1);
//                                editor.apply();
//                                RealmController.updateGroup(o.getGroupName(), true, realm);
//                                st[0] = true;
//                                checkBox.setChecked(true);
//                                RealmController.updateObjectsInGroupRealm(o.getGroupName(), realm, context, true);
//                                FragmentGroupObjectsActivity.getArgument(context);
//                            }
//                        }
//                    }
//                }
//                FragmentGroupObjectsActivity.getArgument(context);
//                FragmentAllObjectActivity.getArgument(context);
//                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (!isChecked) {
//                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
                    RealmResults<ObjectsInGroupRealm> objectsInGroupRealms = RealmController.getObjects(realm, listTitle);
                    int position = -1;
                    for (ObjectDefExtends objectDefExtends : Singleton.getInstance().getListaODE()) {
                        for (ObjectsInGroupRealm o : objectsInGroupRealms) {
                            if (o.getName().equals(objectDefExtends.name)) {
                                position = Singleton.getInstance().getListaODE().indexOf(objectDefExtends);
                                Singleton.getInstance().getListaODE().get(position).visible = false;
                                editor.putInt(Singleton.getInstance().getListaODE().get(position).id.toString(), 0);
                                editor.apply();
                                RealmController.updateGroup(o.getGroupName(), false, realm);
                                RealmController.updateObjectsInGroupRealm(o.getGroupName(), realm, context, false);
                                FragmentGroupObjectsActivity.getArgument(context);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    selected.remove(Integer.valueOf(listPosition));
                } else {
//                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
                    selected.add(listPosition);
                    RealmResults<ObjectsInGroupRealm> objectsInGroupRealms = RealmController.getObjects(realm, listTitle);
                    int position = -1;
                    for (ObjectDefExtends objectDefExtends : Singleton.getInstance().getListaODE()) {
                        for (ObjectsInGroupRealm o : objectsInGroupRealms) {
                            if (o.getName().equals(objectDefExtends.name)) {
                                position = Singleton.getInstance().getListaODE().indexOf(objectDefExtends);
                                Singleton.getInstance().getListaODE().get(position).visible = true;
                                editor.putInt(Singleton.getInstance().getListaODE().get(position).id.toString(), 1);
                                editor.apply();
                                RealmController.updateGroup(o.getGroupName(), true, realm);
                                st[0] = true;
                                checkBox.setChecked(true);
                                RealmController.updateObjectsInGroupRealm(o.getGroupName(), realm, context, true);
                                FragmentGroupObjectsActivity.getArgument(context);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                FragmentGroupObjectsActivity.getArgument(context);
                FragmentAllObjectActivity.getArgument(context);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
        checkBox.setChecked(RealmController.getGroup(listTitleTextView.getText().toString(), realm).isSelect());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really can't understand what you are trying to ask!

Comment: @Jordan I have a ExpandableListView . In group View I have a textView and checkBox when I  click in checkbox I will see a childView and I don't want to

Comment: simply set a click listener for checkbox & the group will stop expanding

Comment: @Jordan I have a on checkBox click listener but when I see a childView and click a checkbox I see only groupView

Comment: So you don't want to collapse or expand a group whenever you click the checkbox. Am i right?

Comment: @Jordan yes , when I click a CheckBox I don't want to change a view

Comment: Comment everything  that you have written in onClick method and then try

Comment: @Jordan now is work , but if I want to do what I have in onClick checkBox ? In childView I have too checkBox and when in gruopView checkbox changed checked I want to changed in childView

Comment: implement OnCheckedChangeListener() for the checkbox and do anything you want to do in it

Comment: @Jordan when I put my code to OnCheckedChangeListener()  a view is changed

Comment: So you are manually collapsing/expanding that view

Comment: @Jordan I edit my  post and I put my full code for my adapter

Comment: Please try debugging it!